# Braintree Payments Static Or Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, paypal, c++builder, braintree, braintree-rails

I am trying to find a static or dynamic (.a or .dylib) library for Braintree Payments (https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios) for use in Embarcadero's RAD Studio (as I cant import the Xcode proj!). I tried to compile the project to a static library but got various compiler and then linking issues that I really didn't understand.

If anyone has managed to create a static library from it or has one they could point me in the right direction of I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't have the tools or processes to be a *web directory*.  Perhaps you could contact Braintree support?

Comment: @DrewDormann wasn't meant as a post for support but more of an outreach to other developer's who may have create a library for Braintree. My appologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work as a developer at Braintree. Braintree does not offer a pre-built static library at this time, but we are considering adding this option in a future release. I recommend contacting support (support@braintreepayments.com) if you need help and/or would like to give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build an iOS app using RAD Studio on Windows instead of XCode?

I would avoid that approach for two reasons. First, I wouldn't expect the RAD tools to be able to keep up with iOS features, so development would always lag behind. Second, it technically breaks the Apple development agreement, so there's a small risk your app could get rejected as a result.

Comment: Yes , only as it allows deployment to Android across one codebase for pretty basic apps. I still do a lot of development in xCode but can relatively easily bridge into the OC classes for frameworks with xcode. However, if you can tell me where in the agreement it says this I will definitely get a refund as they would have misrepresented the product to us. Thanks @tom